# Updating UI when working with OperationQueue

Tags: swift, blockoperation, operationqueue

I have an operation queue setup as follows:

```
let queue = OperationQueue()
queue.name = "com.company.myQueue"
queue.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 64
...
var current = 0
var totalCount = someArray.count
for i in someArray {
... 
   let op = BlockOperation {
   ... // do some database queries
   current += 1
   }

   op.completionBlock = {
     DispatchQueue.main.async {
     let nData: [String: CGFloat] = ["value": CGFloat(current/totalCount)]
     NotificationCenter.default.post(name:Notification.Name(rawValue: "update"), object: nil, userInfo: nData)
   }

   queue.addOperation(op)
}
```

In my `ViewController` I listen for the notification and update a `UILabel` with the percentage. Problem is though I don't get any intermediate values... it jumps from being `0` directly to `100` once all the operations are done.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but I might suggest `extension Notification.Name { static let update = Notification.Name(rawValue: "update") }`. Then you can do things like `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .update, object: nil, userInfo: nData)`. And I’d advise against a `maxConcurrentOperation` count of 64, because you can easily exhaust the limited number of worker threads if you do that. You should generally stay below 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `CGFloat(current / totalCount)`. That does the integer math first, and then converts it to a float. You should flip that around to `CGFloat(current) / CGFloat(totalCount)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can move your notification send function directly in op.completionBlock (without dispatching it in main thread).

Edit (comments) :

```swift
let queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.name = "com.company.myQueue"
    queue.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 64

let array = ["", "", "", "", "", ]

var current = 0
var totalCount = array.count

for _ in array {
    let op = BlockOperation { current += 1 ; print(current) }
        op.completionBlock = {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "update"), object: nil, userInfo: ["value": CGFloat(current / totalCount)])
            }
        }

   queue.addOperation(op)
}

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: "update"), object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
    print(notification.userInfo)
}
```

Edit 2 (comments) :
You should make your percentage by float casting current and totalCount before dividing them.

```swift
CGFloat(current) / CGFloat(totalCount)
'''
```

Comment: doesn't change the result.

Comment: In case : your array is bigger than 1 entry ?

Comment: It has about 6000 elements

Comment: with a `print(current/totalCount)` at the same place of your notification send call : only called once ?

Comment: No called for each element, just stating `0.0 done`, `0.0 done` - and then the last entry is `1.0 done`